# Regex expression help using Python

Tags: python, regex

My mind is getting a little numb with `regex`.  I need to come up with a regular expression to match any of the following scenarios, but so far I have only come up with the following expression that isn't quite working:

```
(package)(\.)(path)(\s+)(=)( )(').*?..*?..*?..*?(.).*?(')
```

I need to build two different expressions.

Expression #1 should match any of the following strings.

```
package.path = 'any string or path here'
package.path = "any string or path here"
package.path='any string or path here'
package.path="any string or path here"
```

Expression #2. should match any of the following strings.

```
package.path = package.path .. 'any string or path here'
package.path = package.path .. "any string or path here"
package.path = package.path..'any string or path here'
package.path = package.path.."any string or path here"
package.path=package.path .. 'any string or path here'
package.path=package.path .. "any string or path here"
```

I would appreciate any help from a Regex Guru out there.

Thanks.

Comment: for starters, `.` is a special char in regex, you'll want to escape it with `\.`

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on what might constitute "any string or path"?  Do the paths contain forward slashes or back slashes?  Do they contain drive letters?  Do the strings only contain numbers and letters, or could they contain other characters or even whitespace?  In the second part, do you need to match a literal `..` or does that symbolize something else?

Comment: ^ or put it in a character class (I tend to think they are easier on the eyes than escaping): `[.]`.

Comment: `\s+` *requires* space. Sounds like you want space to be optional. That should be `\s*`.

Comment: `\s?` (which many folks are suggesting) is only correct if the most you could have is a single space character. Is that the case, or could there be runs of more than one space?

Comment: The "any string or path" could be anything.  It could be a file system path on unix, linux, mac, windows and could contain any characters or spaces.

Comment: ...also, I'd differ from most of the current answers by suggesting `[.]` instead of `\.` when you want to escape a literal `.` -- yes, it's an extra character, but it's easier to read.

Comment: @user2643864, I'm not talking about spaces within the paths; I'm talking about the optional syntactical spaces.

Comment: Additionally, using `\s` wouldn't even be appropriate here, since it matches any whitespace character, not just a space.  I doubt the OP wants to match newlines.  Would be best to just use ` *`

Comment: One more thing: do you explicitly want two separate regex patterns, with one only matching the first examples and none of the second examples, while the other regex does the opposite?  Or would it be acceptable or even preferable to have a single regex that works for both?

Comment: I would like two separate regex patterns because of the test I am running.  I would fail if one pattern exists where I would pass if another exists.  Thought it would be easiest to handle that in two separate patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `.` is a special char in regex, you'll want to escape it with `\.`

then, `+` means `one or more`. Your spaces are present `0 or 1` times, which is indicated by `?`

then, character classes are indicated using `[]`, so your quotes can be classified as `['"]`

finally, we can use `\1` to recall the matched quote

With that in mind, your first expression is

```
package\.path\s?=\s?(['"]).*\1
```

and the second is

```
package\.path\s?=\s?package\.path\s?\.\.\s?(['"]).*\1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `package\.path\s?=\s?(package\.path)?(\s\.\.\s)?('|").*?('|")` regex:

```
import re

data = """package.path = 'any string or path here'
package.path = "any string or path here"
package.path='any string or path here'
package.path="any string or path here"
package.path = package.path .. 'any string or path here'
package.path = package.path .. "any string or path here"
package.path=package.path .. 'any string or path here'
package.path=package.path .. "any string or path here"
"""


pattern = re.compile(r"""package\.path\s?=\s?(package\.path)?(\s\.\.\s)?('|").*?('|")""")
for line in data.splitlines(False):
    match = pattern.match(line)
    print match.group(0) if match else "No match"
```

Answer (score 1):

Expression #1: package.path\s?=\s?['"][\w\s]+['"] 
Expression #2: package.path\s?=\s?package.path\s..\s['"][\w\s]+['"]